# About the definition of complex multiplication

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis

Some people say that the complex product is the way it is to respect the **distributive law of multiplication**. However, the distributive law acts in the whole number, like:

$$(a+b)(c+d) = ac + ad + bc + bd$$

The multiplication for complex numbers would be something in the form:

$$(z_1+z_2)(z_3+z_4) = z_1z_3 + z_1z_4 + z_2z_3 + z_2z_4$$

Where $z_n$ is a complex number in the form $a+bi$

I don't see why the distributive law must act **inside the number**:

$$(a+bi)(c+di) = ac + adi + bci - bd^2$$

What's the real reason for this definition?

Comment: Rewrite one of your numbers as $z = (a + 0i) + (0 + bi)$, now appeal to your stated property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z_1 = a, z_2 = bi, z_3 = c, z_4 = di$.
Then the rule
\begin{equation*}
\tag{$\spadesuit$}(z_1 + z_2)(z_3 + z_4) = z_1 z_3 + z_1 z_4 + z_2 z_3 + z_2 z_4
\end{equation*}
tells us that
\begin{align*}
(a + bi)(c + di) &= ac + adi + bci + bd i^2 \\
 &= ac - bd + (ad + bc)i.
\end{align*}
So if we want ($\spadesuit$) to be true, we are forced to use the standard formula for multiplication of complex numbers.